# How to create first Server Instance in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have installed SQL Server and SSMS. And I open SSMS. The Connect to Database Engine Dialog is shown. But the Server Name is empty.

I don't know how to create a Server Name.
And I don't know where.
I also have tried to choose a fullpath name or local. But that doesn't work.

Can anybody help me? Oh... for both (SQL Server Express plus Management Studio I have the latest version).

Comment: SQL Server Express is usually installed as named instance "SQLEXPRESS". If installed locally, try entering ".\SQLEXPRESS" for the server name. To connect to a remote instance, "RemoteHostName\SQLEXPRESS".

Answer (score 0):

In the drop down box for "Server Name" choose the option for `<Browse for more...>`.  This will then give you a further window where you should see your instance listed under Local Servers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the following:

1. You have installed Sql Server *(not just SSMS)*, and during installation you specified a SQL Server instance for your computer and you DIDN'T specify an instance name. In that case you must

   1. Make sure that the SQL Server service, called MSSQLSERVER, is running.
   2. Connect to it with the name `.` (yes, just a dot)
2. You have installed Sql Server, and during installation you specified a SQL Server instance for your computer and you DID specify an instance name. In that case you must

   1. Make sure that the SQL Server service, called MSSQLSERVER, is running.
   2. Connect to it with the name `.\InstanceName`
3. You have install Sql Server Express.

   1. Make sure that the SQL Server Express service is running. (I think the service name is also MSSQLSERVER)
   2. Connect to it with the name `.\SqlExpress`
4. You have not installed any Sql Server version but you may have installed Visual Studio or something that include Sql tools, including LocalDb

   1. start a localdb instance running with a command that is something like this (depending on your installed version):
      `'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\SqlLocalDB.exe' start`
   2. Connect to it with the name, `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb`
5. You have not installed any Sql Server instance on your machine, and you are expecting to find a Sql Server instance somewhere on your network.

   1. In this case you need someone who knows, to tell you the server name.

(You can create and start localdb instances with other names, MSSQLLocalDb is just the default or not having specified a name)

Start a service with e.g. PowerShell: `Start-Service MSSQLSERVER` or look for the service in the Windows' ⚙️ `Services` GUI you can find from Start Menu search.